# How to read input from a user and replace a text in a .txt file with the inputed text on shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am trying to read input from user and update a .txt file by replacing a word.
Is there any possibility to do that? If there please help me. I want this to done using **SHELL** Script on **Ubuntu OS**.

**Example:**

I want to replace the word "**Kid**" From the below .Txt file with a user input "**boys**".

*.Txt file content:*

```
I love that kid that they are playing on the ground.
```

**Step by Step :**

1. Start the Shell Program.
2. Receive a Input from user to $a.
3. Read .txt file and find the word "**Kid**".
4. Replace the "Kid" Word from the .txt file with the user input $a.

That's all I want to do.

Comment: What have you tried ? What do you exactly whant to do ? Please give us a piece of code and/or an example.

Comment: Just read a text input from user and replace a specified word from a .txt file with the text that input by the user.

Comment: Have you looked at `sed`. Like `sed -i.bak "s/oldname/newname/" filename`?

Comment: No. Please tell me the procedure to that.

Comment: I got some tutorial from https://gist.github.com/benlumley/1342665 but I want it to done on a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

WORD="foo" # what to find
TXT_FILE="/tmp/lala.txt" # where

# get the new word from user
read -p "With what \"$WORD\" should be replaced ? " newword

# replace, preserving capitalization
output=$(cat "$TXT_FILE" | sed "s/${WORD^}/${newword^}/g" | sed "s/$WORD/$newword/ig")
echo "$output" > "$TXT_FILE"
echo "done"
```

If you run it, you get:

```
/tmp » cat lala.txt 
Foo is riding a bike, while Frank is sunbathing. 
Suddenly, Foo falls. And also Foo, foo, foo.

/tmp » ./lala.sh     
With what "foo" should be replaced ? bar
done

/tmp » cat lala.txt 
Bar is riding a bike, while Frank is sunbathing. 
Suddenly, Bar falls. And also Bar, bar, bar.
```

Comment: Yes. Is that file save automatically after making the changes?

Comment: Can I do the same method to change words from a .JS file? I am asking this questions because, Now I don't have a Ubuntu OS running on my PC.

Comment: yes, you can use it with any kind of files. But beware: if the words you find/replace contain special chars, you may have some surprise. The best way to go is to understand the script and tune it to suit your needs.

Comment: Is there is any video tutorial or reference that might useful to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: I suggest you read/follow a tutorial on the command `sed` on the internet. Then, play with it a while.

Comment: If my answer helps you, please don't forget to upvote it and to mark your post as answered (checkmark on the left).

Comment: How to mark as answered? I Up voted you answer but its not voting intend of increasing the vote count, I received a message showed in my Display. "You need more reputation to vote".

Comment: No worries, just use the checkmark on the left, the upvote is not so important. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks man. Would you like to share your Email address with me. If I can ask question. Please just);

Comment: The sed line and the one following it can be simplified to `sed -i "s/${WORD^}/{newword^}/g;s/$WORD/$newword/ig" "$TXT_FILE"`, which avoids spawning a bunch of subshells and having sed process the file multiple times. Also, variable names in all caps are more likely to clash with existing variables, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/3266847

Comment: pluse-uno for usable answer and technical support ;-) Good luck to all.